# Как прокинуть второе свойство в конвертер Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Есть entity `Data` и класс ее конфигурации. Данные `Value` хранятся в строковом виде. Как можно прокинуть `Type`, чтобы преобразовать `Value` в нужный тип? Можно ли это сделать если `Type` будет не в текущей, а в связанной сущности?

```
public enum DataType
{
    Date,
    Decimal,
    String,
    Json
}

public class Data
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DataType Type { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }
}


public class DataEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Data>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Data> builder)
    {
        builder
            .Property(e => e.Value)
            .HasConversion(
                v => v.ToString(),
                v => /* Connvert using Type property */);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если они хранятся в стоковом, почему не сделать `public string Value`?

Comment: К сущности происходит обращение из разных мест, логику преобразования нужно куда-то инкапсулировать.

Comment: Как вариант сделать NotMapped метод в классе сущности, который бы преобразовывал Value к нужному типу? И тем самым обращаться из разных мест, получая нужный тип данных. Тогда отпадает необходимость в Type.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ:

```cs
public abstract class Data
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    internal Data() { } // если вы не хотите, чтоб др. сборки могли наследовать этот
                        // класс (в .NET нет нормального способа ограничить наследование)

    public abstract override string ToString();
    public abstract object AsObject();
    public virtual Type GetObjectType() => AsObject().GetType();
}
```

```cs
public sealed /*optional*/ class StringData : Data
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public StringData(string? value) => Value = value ?? "";

    public override stirng ToString() => Value;
    public override object AsObject() => Value;
    public override Type GetObjectType() => typeof(string);

    public static implicit operator string(StringData data)
    {
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

        return data.ToString(); // для устойчивости к изменениям
    }
    public static implicit operator StringData(string str) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Использование:

```cs
public class DataEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Data>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Data> builder)
    {
        builder
            .Property(e => e.AsObject())
            .HasConversion(
                v => v.ToString(),
                v => /*convert using GetObjectType()*/);
    }
}
```

---

Вы можете заменить/совместить `GetObjectType()` на/с атрибут/-ом `DataObjectTypeAttribute`, например:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiply = false, Inherit = false
    /*if 'sealed class StringData'*/)]
public sealed class DataObjectTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type ObjectType { get; }

    public DataObjectTypeAttribute(Type objectType) { /*...*/ }
}
```

```cs
[DataObjectType(typeof(string))]
public sealed class StringData : Data
{
    // ...
}
```

```cs
using System.Reflection;
// ...
// in Data type
// ...
public static Type GetObjectType(Type dataType)
{
    if (dataType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dataType");
    if (!dataType.IsSubclassOf(Data))
        throw new ArgumentException("Data type must be subclass of 'Data' type", "dataType");

    return dataType.GetCustomAttribute<DataObjectTypeAttribute>()?.ObjectType ??
        typeof(object); // или выбросить исключение, если атрибут не найден
}
// ...
```

Использование:

```cs
public class DataEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Data>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Data> builder)
    {
        builder
            .Property(e => e.AsObject())
            .HasConversion(
                v => v.ToString(),
                v => /*convert using Data.GetObjectType(e.GetType())*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: Обычно вместо `protected private void Trash();` делают `internal` конструктор...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Извините, исправлю (я об такой "фиче" узнал из WPF, и там писало, что вы не переопределили `internal` методы, ну я и начал юзать `internal`/`protected private`)

Comment: Тут речь немного о другом, DataType - enum, его значение получаем из столбца рядом с Value

Answer (score 1):

Можно взять и создать вот такие классы:

```cs
public static class DataServices
{
    public static void Check(this DataType dataType)
    {
        // ...
    }
    public static Type GetClrType(this DataType dataTypew)
    {
        // ...
    }
    public static DataType GetDataType(Type clrType)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```cs
public readonly struct DataAdapter // or 'DataConverter'
{
    public object Adapt /*or 'Convert'*/(string data, DataType dataType)
    {
        dataType.Check();

        return dataType switch
        {
            DataType.String => data;
            DataType.Decimal => decimal.Parse(data);
            DataType.DateTime => DateTime.Parse(data);
            DataType.Json => // ...
            // в случае ошибки исключение будет получено из метода DataServices.Check
            _ => throw new InvalidProgramException();
        }
    }
    public object Adapt(string data, out DataType dataType)
    {
        if (decimal.TryParse(data, out var dec))
        {
            dataType = DataType.Decimal;

            return dec;
        }
        else if (DateTime.TryParse(data, out var dateTime))
        {
            dataType = DataType.DateTime;

            return dateTime;
        }
        else if (/*try parse data as json*/)
        {
            dataType = DataType.Json;

            return json;
        }
        else
        {
            dataType = DataType.String;

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Лучше переделать класс `Data`:

```cs
public class Data
{
    string data;

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public object Data
    {
        get => data;
        set
        {
            if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

            data = value;
            CachedData = null;
        }
    }
    public DataType DataType { get; set; }
    public string? CachedData { get; private set; } // optional

    public void SetData(string data)
    {
        DataType dataType;

        Data = new DataAdapter().Adapt(data, out dataType);
        DataType = dataType;
        CachedData = data;
    }
}
```